# Getting memory leak in while adding button on Status bar in my iPhone project

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leak while adding button on status bar, whaen I am tries to release the leak object, the button wont display on status bar.

http://screencast.com/t/d20XBvYBcgu
Above is screenshot for my project leak

Answer (score 0):

auto release enable when creating a object

```
UIWindow *overlapview = [[UIWindow new]autorelrease];
```

Comment: tried for the same but button not getting displayed on status bar

Answer (score 0):

You own the object returned by functions that start with "init", "new", "copy", "mutalbelCopy" and you're responsible to release objects you own.

In your case, you own the object "overlapview" and it's not released. It's a leak.

Comment: Yes, but when I am tried for the same my button is not getting displayed

Comment: Post more code. In the pic you provided all I can see is that overlap view is not used or retained by any other object. It'll be released earlier than you thought if it is autoreleased. As a result, button will not display.

Comment: I found one solution, rather go with new I alloc init the overlap and set its property and all is fine now.

Comment: "new" is just a combination of "alloc" and "init" in Objective-C. I don't think "new" is the problem here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604878/object-sent-autorelease-too-many-times-getting-this-leak-for-my-iphone-app